# lambda function not able to send custom metric to datadog through dd-trace npm library

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, datadog, aws-sam-cli, datadog-dashboard

I am trying to send custom metric from lambda functions to datadog. I have already configured lambda to send custom metric to lambda by following this [this](https://docs.datadoghq.com/serverless/installation/nodejs/?tab=custom) (Following custom installation).
I have already:

1. Installed the Datadog Lambda library
2. Installed the Datadog Lambda Extension

This is how my lambda function code looks like

```
require("dotenv").config();
const tracer = require("dd-trace").init();
let response;

exports.lambdaHandler = tracer.wrap(
  "twilio.DDTraceFunction",
  async (event, context) => {
    try {
      tracer.dogstatsd.increment("example_metric.increment", 1, [
        "environment:dev",
      ]);
      tracer.dogstatsd.decrement("example_metric.decrement", 1, [
        "environment:dev",
      ]);

      response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          message: "hello world",
        }),
      };
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("err===============>", err);

      return {
        statusCode: 500,
        body: JSON.stringify("An error occurred"),
      };
    }

    return response;
  }
);
```

Currently I am trying to test it locally using aws sam cli. This is Error that I am encountering with

```
➜  sam-app sam local invoke DDTraceFunction                    
Invoking /opt/nodejs/node_modules/datadog-lambda-js/handler.handler (nodejs14.x)                                                          
arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:464622532012:layer:Datadog-Extension:10 is already cached. Skipping download                                    
arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:464622532012:layer:Datadog-Node14-x:62 is already cached. Skipping download                                     
Local image is up-to-date                                                                                                                 
Using local image: samcli/lambda-nodejs:14-x86_64-12d24702a7805bbe910f9c1a2.                                                              
                                                                                                                                          
Mounting /Users/global/Desktop/test/datadog/sam-app/lib-dd-trace as /var/task:ro,delegated, inside runtime container                  
START RequestId: a3b8482b-2d9d-4094-b7d7-dc82c747d66e Version: $LATEST
2023-08-18T04:03:24.243Z    a3b8482b-2d9d-4094-b7d7-dc82c747d66e    INFO    err===============> TypeError: Cannot read property 'incre    at step (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/datadog-lambda-js/index.js:44:23)ndex.js:168:62)acer.js:42:29).js:57:14)
END RequestId: a3b8482b-2d9d-4094-b7d7-dc82c747d66e
REPORT RequestId: a3b8482b-2d9d-4094-b7d7-dc82c747d66e  Init Duration: 0.55 ms  Duration: 3807.39 ms    Billed Duration: 3808 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 128 MB 
{"statusCode": 500, "body": "\"An error occurred\""}%
```

This is how my function looks in template.yml looks

```
  DDTraceFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: lib-dd-trace/
      Handler: /opt/nodejs/node_modules/datadog-lambda-js/handler.handler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Environment:
        Variables:
          DD_SERVERLESS_LOGS_ENABLED: true
          DD_TRACE_ENABLED: true
          DD_LAMBDA_HANDLER: app.lambdaHandler
      Layers:
        - arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:464622532012:layer:Datadog-Extension:10 
        - arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:464622532012:layer:Datadog-Node14-x:62
```

DD_API_KEY, DD_SITE, DD_SERVERLESS_LOGS_ENABLED, DD_TRACE_ENABLED, DD_LOGS_INJECTION env variable are already set template.yml global's section.

I am not able to access dogstatsd in tracer function. I believe dogstatsd is responsible for sending these metrics to datadog, but in my case tracer.dogstatsd is coming as undefined. In case dogstatsd is not available in tracer, which function of tracer shall I use to send custom metric [count metric, rate metric , set metric etc](https://docs.datadoghq.com/metrics/custom_metrics/dogstatsd_metrics_submission/) to datadog.
Any help is really appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update:

> A Lambda function may launch many concurrent execution environments when traffic increases. The function may submit count or gauge metric points that overwrite each other and cause undercounted results.
>
> To avoid this problem, custom metrics generated by Lambda functions are submitted as **distributions** because distribution metric points are aggregated on the Datadog backend, and every metric point counts.
>
> https://docs.datadoghq.com/serverless/custom_metrics/#understanding-distribution-metrics

### Original Answer:

Since you already have the `datadog-lambda-js`, you can use that instead of `dd-trace` directly.

```
const { sendDistributionMetric } = require('datadog-lambda-js');

exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
    try {
        sendDistributionMetric(
            'example_metric.increment',
            1,
            'environment:dev',
            'order:online'
        );

        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: "hello world",
            }),
        };
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("err===============>", err);

        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify("An error occurred"),
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response @RobinThomas, by installation I mean The Datadog Lambda Library is imported as a lambda layer(which is equal to manually installation).  I came across this snippet that you have provided in the datadog official docs but the problem here is that the requirement is there to implement the count, rate, set type of metrics as well, for distribution metric we can  use 'sendDistributionMetric' of 'datadog-lambda-js' but  how can we implement the rest types of metrics. Can you help ?

Comment: so the motive here is to send all types of metric from lambda function to datadog dashboard. Is it possible with datadog-lambda-js? I explored datadog-lambda-js and find out that we have only sendDistributionMetric & sendDistributionMetricWithDate for sending custom metric. I didn't find any method to send count, rate, gauge, set type of metric

Comment: Unfortunately, `datadog-lambda-js` allows sending custom metrics by only `sendDistributionMetric` and `sendDistributionMetricWithDate`. There is no options for count, rate or gauge options.

Comment: This is because DataDog supports only distribution metric for serverless (AWS lambdas). I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: That means dd-trace library can't be utilised for sending custom metrics but only traces , right ?

Comment: You can send distribution custom metric. You just cant do count, rate and gauge custom metric with AWS lambda.

Comment: just making the understanding clear, we can only send distribution metrics from aws lambda to datadog by utilising datadog-lambda-js, we cant use dd-trace library to send distribution metrics, dd-trace can only be used to send traces to datadog, right ?

Comment: `dd-trace` is the library that `datadog-lambda-js` is using internally to send the metrics. https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-lambda-js/pull/413/files

Comment: @babita-bisht if that clarifies everything, can you kindly accept my answer? :)

Comment: Thanks @robin-thomas for the answer and clarification in the comment section, am still reviewing it further,  will mark your answer as true soon.